# SymmetricDS File Synchronization Router

Tags: symmetricds

I have 3 nodes (`corp`, `store-1`, `store-2`). I want to do file synchronization that filtering based on node's `external.id`. So the file is synchronizing to the right nodes (not to all nodes). I read the docs that column match router can do filtered synchronization, but the example is in database synchronization.

How to do that in file synchronization? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the same [router](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_router_types) linked through [file_trigger_router to your file_trigger](http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.7/html/user-guide.html#_file_synchronization) for filtering which files go to which target nodes

here's an example: http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.5/html-single/user-guide.html#filesync-example-2

```
INSERT INTO sym_file_trigger
  (trigger_id,base_dir,recurse,includes_files,excludes_files,sync_on_create,
  sync_on_modified,sync_on_delete,before_copy_script,after_copy_script,create_time,
  last_update_by,last_update_time)
VALUES
  ('node_specific','/filesync/server/nodes',1,null,null,1,1,1,'',null,
  current_timestamp,'example',current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO sym_file_trigger_router
  (trigger_id,router_id,enabled,initial_load_enabled,target_base_dir,
  conflict_strategy,create_time,last_update_by,last_update_time)
VALUES
  ('node_specific','router_files_to_node',1,1,'/filesync/clients','SOURCE_WINS',
  current_timestamp,'example',current_timestamp);

INSERT INTO sym_router
  (router_id,target_catalog_name,target_schema_name,target_table_name,
   source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,router_type,router_expression,
   sync_on_update,sync_on_insert,sync_on_delete,create_time,last_update_by,
   last_update_time)
VALUES
  ('router_files_to_node',null,null,null,'server','client','column',
  'RELATIVE_DIR = :NODE_ID ',1,1,1,current_timestamp,'example', current_timestamp);
```

Comment: can you give me example of the `sym_router` with `router_expression`? I have no idea

Comment: I just want to ask, router expression for  this synchronization. Must I create one table for tracking the file? How to connect the table with the real file? Just it.

Comment: insert your configuration in the table sym_file_trigger. it will define which directory to sync

Comment: Yeah I already did file synchronization but no filtering mode before I ask this question

Comment: link it through sym_file_trigger_router to an existing sym_router that does the filtering

Comment: And again, what is the `router_expression`?

Comment: it depends on which type of routing has been chosen

Comment: How to add `ID_STORE=:EXTERNAL_ID` in file sync?

Comment: I already did all before I ask this, column match router and db sync. But I cannot link column match router with file sync because I don't know how file sync hold any column datas for route filtering

Comment: you'll need another sym_router with an expression to route files as explained here: http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.5/html-single/user-guide.html#filesync-example-2

Comment: ah nice, this should be added on newest user guide. Thanks!